# Apex is deselecting my radio buttons

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, radio-button

Basically I want an apex method to run when a radio button has been selected. I also want the image used as the radio button to change. But it seems when the method runs the radio button is unselected and image reverts to the original. If I take out the call to the apex method the radio buttons change images as on select as it should. I've got a feeling as soon as the apex runs it redrawing the screen and removing the user's selection :(

```
<apex:actionFunction name="CallmySad" action="{!MethSad}"/>
<input id="sad" class="input-hidden" type="radio" name="emotion" onclick="JavaSad()"/>  
<label for="sad">
    <img id="sadimage" width="80vw" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.sad)}" alt="I'm sad"/>
</label>
```

Script:

```
function JavaSad() {
    CallmySad();
    document.getElementById("sadimage").src = "{!URLFOR($Resource.sadfill)}";
}
```

I basically have faces the user can click for my feedback visualforce.

Comment: unless you are using `rerender=`, any call to the controller will refresh the entire page when the action method returns.  Thus, the controller variables will be used to refresh all page elements that reference controller properties/getXX methods.

Comment: I was able to solve this by using the 'rerender="none"' inside my actionfunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any call to the controller that is not a partial page update (Ajax) will refresh the entire page using the values from the controller variables (getters) or controller getXXX methods

As you have:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="CallmySad" action="{!MethSad}"/>
```

the controller action method `MethSad` is invoked and the entire page is refreshed.

By adding `rerender=xxx` to the action method, the controller method will be invoked but only the component on the page identified by id="xxx" will be refreshed and only that component (and children)'s values will be fetched from the controller.

Note that xxx can be a list of ids as in `rerender="xxx,yyy,..."`

- [apex:actionFunction doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)
- [Partial page Updates using Ajax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_ajax.htm?search_text=partial%20page)
- [Rerender when the id doesn;t appear on a component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50407/what-happens-when-rerender-nothing)
- [Detailed actionFunction example with partial page update (pg 127)](https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf)